# Make rectangular matrix of correlation values in R, possibly using corrplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, correlation, r-corrplot

I want to make a matrix of correlation values in R. However, I am not comparing the parameters to themselves, so it isn't your typical corrplot that is a triangle and mirrored over a diagonal axis. I actually *already have the correlation values*.

I was just hoping to recruit the `corrplot` function (from [corrplot package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/corrplot/vignettes/corrplot-intro.html)), which produces images like the following:

[image: picture]

My data, already containing the correlation values I want to plot, is:

```
            X    animal.1   animal.2     animal.3    animal.4   animal.5
1 parameter 1  0.10258087  0.3338782  0.150246554  0.07295133  0.2484152
2 parameter 2  0.04205748  0.4062727 -0.002101464  0.12068818  0.2951127
3 parameter 3  0.11264488  0.4114954  0.067145776  0.13361071  0.3246052
4 parameter 4 -0.02261649 -0.2426341  0.108042167 -0.12820517 -0.2005686
5 parameter 5 -0.01576384 -0.2300852  0.112941655 -0.12391976 -0.1906473
6 parameter 6 -0.09749030 -0.3110920  0.021994297 -0.13570257 -0.2557532
```

I want the plot to look like a corrplot, but it will be a full rectangle. I want the circles of varying diameters, and the two different colors for positive or negative values, and the color gradient along the side of the plot. In essence I want the corrplot theme of a rectangular table of values.

I have also asked to see if asterisks could be placed over the grid squares with significant (p<0.05) p-values. I am now attaching a dput file of the p-value matrix

```
structure(list(X = structure(1:6, .Label = c("parameter 1", "parameter 2", 
"parameter 3", "parameter 4", "parameter 5", "parameter 6"), class = "factor"), 
Animal.1 = c(0.2454906, 0.63471, 0.2019519, 0.7984066, 0.8587147, 
0.2698293), Animal.2 = c(0.000103586, 1.62e-06, 1.15e-06, 
0.005412082, 0.008451775, 0.000315107), Animal.3 = c(0.08796553, 
0.9810688, 0.447827, 0.2211191, 0.2007585, 0.8038392), Animal.4 = c(0.4094627, 
0.1713835, 0.1296492, 0.1460429, 0.1601174, 0.1236984), Animal.5 = c(0.004374306, 
0.000653099, 0.00016464, 0.02213469, 0.0298038, 0.003315349
)), .Names = c("X", "animal.1", "animal.2", "animal.3", "animal.4", 
"animal.5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Please do not provide your data as an image.  No one wants to type it all in again. Instead, use `dput` to create a text version of your data and paste the result into your question. Also, please provide the code that you used to create the corrplot that you have now  You probably should read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Both pictures were meant to demonstrate what I wanted. I took a picture of a random corrplot picture example I found online. My data was provided merely to demonstrate the shape of the plot I wanted. I don't know what dput is. I'm new to stackoverflow

Comment: Did that work? I think I did the dput correct

Comment: You must have got the correlation values from some data - why not just use the original data, which is what `corrplot` is designed for?

Comment: The original data is not formatted correctly, or otherwise I don't know how to extract bits of data. I am not that R savvy. I do everything clunkily but formulaically

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you just need to transform your df into a matrix and then run the `corrplot` function.

```
library(corrplot)

#Transform data to matrix
matrix_cor<-as.matrix(df[,-1])

#Set row names as df first column
row.names(matrix_cor)<-df[,1]

corrplot(matrix_cor,
         method = "circle")
```

[image: corrplot]

Comment: You did exactly what I was looking for. Upvote times a million, thanks man!

Actually one more thing, is there a way to draw an asterisk over each of the circles, or indicate some other way on the plot, if it is a significant (p<0.05) correlation?

Comment: I extracted a p-value for animal 3 parameter 3 from cor.test and it is not significant like your code shows by putting an asterisk there

Comment: Yeah, sorry, you have to run `cor.mtest` on the original data, not the correlation matrix. So, you can do `result<-cor.mtest("original_data", 
          conf.level = 0.95)` and then `corrplot(matrix_cor, 
         p.mat = result$p, 
         insig = "label_sig",
         sig.level = 0.05, 
         pch.cex = 1.5, 
         pch.col = "black")`

Comment: I just made a new csv matrix by individually copy pasting all the p-values from cor.test. Can you use that instead and overlay it on the plot? I have added that table into the original question

Comment: Also, my original data is a different structure than these simplified datasets I am posting, so I can't reference the original data unfortunately

Comment: Then just save the p.values csv as df2 and do: `matrix_pvalues<-as.matrix(df2[,-1])`, then `row.names(matrix_pvalues)<-df2[,1]` and finally `corrplot(matrix_cor, 
         p.mat = matrix_pvalues, 
         insig = "label_sig",
         sig.level = 0.05, 
         pch.cex = 1.5, 
         pch.col = "black")`

Answer (score 3):

As you tag this question with `ggplot2`, I'm providing you a way to do that using `ggplot2`.

First, you need to reshape both the dataframe containing correlation values (named `df` here) and the one with pvalues (named `df_pval` here). 
For doing that, you can for example use the `pivot_longer` function from `tidyr` package (also part of the `tidyverse` package).

On the dataframe containing pvalues, we will add a column `Label` in order to mark with an asterisk all values below 0.05.

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

corr_values <- df %>% pivot_longer(-X, names_to = "Animal", values_to = "value") 

# Here an extract of the dataframe with correlation values after reshaping it:
  X           Animal    value
  <fct>       <chr>     <dbl>
1 parameter 1 animal.1 0.103 
2 parameter 1 animal.2 0.334 
3 parameter 1 animal.3 0.150 
4 parameter 1 animal.4 0.0730
5 parameter 1 animal.5 0.248 
6 parameter 2 animal.1 0.0421
```

```r
corr_pval <- df_pval %>% 
  pivot_longer(-X, names_to = "Animal", values_to = "p.value") %>%
  mutate(Label = ifelse(p.value < 0.05, "*",NA)) 

# Here an extract of the dataframe obtained
  X           Animal    p.value Label
  <fct>       <chr>       <dbl> <chr>
1 parameter 1 animal.1 0.245    NA   
2 parameter 1 animal.2 0.000104 *    
3 parameter 1 animal.3 0.0880   NA   
4 parameter 1 animal.4 0.409    NA   
5 parameter 1 animal.5 0.00437  *    
6 parameter 2 animal.1 0.635    NA
```

Then, you can use `geom_point` and `geom_tile` to get the heatmap. 
You can also customize, color, size, etc.. of your plot by passing various functions such as `scale_size_continuous` and `scale_color_gradient`.

Finally, you can add asterisk for `pvalues` by calling a new dataframe `corr_pval` into `geom_text` and specify the appropriate `aesthetic` argument:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(corr_values, aes(x = X, y = Animal))+
  geom_tile(color = "black", fill = "white")+
  geom_point(aes(color = value, size = abs(value)))+
  scale_color_gradient2(low = "green", mid = "white", midpoint = 0, high = "red", name = "")+
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(5,15), name = "")+
  geom_text(data = corr_pval, aes(label = Label), size = 8, vjust = 0.7, hjust = 0.5)
```

So, you should get something like that:

[image]